# Delete only a specific query from an URL

Tags: python, parsing, url

SO I have the following URL: https://foo.bar?query1=value1&query2=value2&query3=value3

I'd need a function that can strip just query2 for example, so that the result would be:
https://foo.bar?query1=value1&query3=value3

I think maybe urllib.parse or furl can do this in an easy and clean way?

Comment: Did try to convert it to string and use repalce?

Comment: @NirElbaz how do you replace something that you don't know?

Comment: you know the number of &, find the first one and then the 2nd one and then remove

Comment: @NirElbaz so that's not a replace... also, parameters can be ordered arbitrarily, I'm afraid simply counting the `&` isn't enough.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli , I am not sure I understand, you want remove the 2nd query or you want to remove  the string that is called query2?

Comment: @NirElbaz well, we should ask that to OP. The question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) as it's designed exactly for these purposes. I'm unclear the reason for anyone reinventing the wheel here.

Basically 3 steps:

1. Use urlparse to parse the url into it's component parts
2. Use parse_qs to parse the query string part of that keeping blanks (if relevant intact)
3. Remove the erroneous query2 and re-encode the query string and url back

From the docs:

> Parse a URL into six components, returning a 6-item named tuple. This
> corresponds to the general structure of a URL:
> scheme://netloc/path;parameters?query#fragment. Each tuple item is a
> string, possibly empty.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlencode, parse_qs, urlunparse
url = "https://foo.bar?query1=value1&query2=value2&query3=value3"
url_bits = list(urlparse(url))
print(url_bits)

query_string = parse_qs(url_bits[4], keep_blank_values=True)
print(query_string)

del(query_string['query2'])
url_bits[4] = urlencode(query_string, doseq=True)
new_url = urlunparse(url_bits)

print(new_url)

# >>>['https', 'foo.bar', '', '', 'query1=value1&query2=value2&query3=value3', '']
# >>>{'query1': ['value1'], 'query2': ['value2'], 'query3': ['value3']}
# >>>https://foo.bar?query1=value1&query3=value3
```

Comment: It seems OP wants to remove the second query, not the query param named `query2`

Comment: I think it's ambiguous but more likely to be that query2 should be removed rather than it's the second query in the string. OP should clarify.

Comment: This work perfectly, even tho I had hoped for a way shorter solution. Probably it would be better using a regex to strip the query delimited by ?/& characters.

Comment: I think you’d end up with a list of matches which then require iterating over, matching to query2 and removing before recreating the url again. This is what the library is already doing. I just broke down the steps to be easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want by position:

```
url="https://foo.bar?query1=value1&query2=value2&query3=value3"

findindex1=url.find("&")
findindex2=url.find("&",findindex1+1)
url=url[0:findindex1]+url[findindex2:len(url)]
```

if you want by the name:

```
url="https://foo.bar?query1=value1&query3=value3&query2=value2"

findindex1=url.find("query2")
findindex2=url.find("&",findindex1+1)
if findindex2==-1:
    url=url[0:findindex1-1]
else:
    url=url[0:findindex1-1]+url[findindex2:len(url)]
```

Comment: I think OP is trying to remove a query parameter with a certain name, not a certain position. So for example, consider `url="https://foo.bar?query1=value1&query3=value3&query2=value2"`, now what?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli It is only a slight change, I will edit my answer to fit both

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could try it with regular expressions.

`re.sub("ThePatternOfTheURL","ThePatternYouWantToHave", "TheInput")`

so it could look something like that

```
pattern = "'(https\:\/\/)([a-zA-Z.?0-9=]+)([&]query2=value2)([&][a-zA-Z0-9=]+)'"

#filters the third group out with query2
filter = r"\1\2\4"
 
yourUrl = "https://foo.bar?query1=value1&query2=value2&query3=value3"

newURL=re.sub(pattern, filter, yourUrl)
```

I think this should work for you